# Accessing Census ACS1 tables in Python

Tags: python, api, census

I want to get ACS1 tables from 2010 to 2021 for B25077_001E variable for NY, NJ at the county subdivision and place level to include only the name of the community, geoid and year in python and store it as a pandas dataframe. Could you please help? Thank you!

```
import requests
import os
import pandas as pd

inputKeyPath r””
inputKeyName = ‘CensusKey.txt’
f = open(inputKeyPath, “r”)
myKey = f.readline()

var_list = [‘B25077_001E’]
endpoint = ‘acs/acs1’
prefix_url = ‘https://api.census.gov/data’
states_terr = [‘34’, ‘36’]
states_in = ‘.’.join(states_terr)
years = range(2010, 2022)
geographies = [‘place’, ‘county subdivision’]
final_df_list = []

for geography in geographies:
    df_list = []
    for year in years:
        base_url = “/“.join([prefix_url, year, endpoint])
        predicates = {}
        get_vars = [‘NAME’, ‘GEO_ID’] + var_list
        predicates[“get”] = ‘,’.join(get_vars)
        predicates[“for”] = f’{geography}:*’
        predicates[“in”] = f’state:{states_in}’
        predicates[“key”] = myKey
        r = requests.get(base_url, params=predicates
        temp_df = pd.DataFrame(r.json())
        final_df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()[1:], column=list(temp_df.loc[0]))
        final_df[‘year’] = year
        final_df.set_index(‘GEO_ID’, inplace=True)
        df_list.append(final_df[[i for i in final_df.columns if i not in [‘state’, ‘county’, geography]]])
    sub_geo_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
        final_df_list.append(sub_geo_df([[i for i in sub_geo_df.columns if i not in [‘state’, ‘county’, geography]]])
```